# Sorting tags by a different criteria

Tags: discussion

When you click on 'Tags' they are sorted by their raw frequency of occurrence (popularity).  The other options available are an alphabetic sort and creation date sort.

I wanted to see a list of tags sorted with the following criteria...

- **Primary key descending**: (raw frequency * number of upvotes on the
  question * 5)
- **Secondary key descending**: (raw frequency * number of responses *
  upvotes on answers * 10)

Is there a way to do this without lots of technical knowledge?

Once I see the report, I might need to adjust the criteria to include whether the answer was accepted or not.  Plus I might need to run the report several times over the course of say, a month.  Plus any other ad-hoc tweaking until I uncovered some insight.

I suspect this has to do with SQL, and I have some credentials in that technology that can be useful.

Please note that my motivation is purely recreational (exactly *what* I'm looking for doesn't matter), I would not suggest this as a site fixture.

Comment: You might want to try [data SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) for this.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to do it in the travel group.

Comment: Thing is you don't have access to those data from the TSE website. You do from data.stackexchange.com though.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not exactly what you asked but here a few queries to tally questions and answers by tag:

- Number of questions and total score of these questions: http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/290643
- Number of questions, total number of answers to these questions and total scores of all answers: http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/290638

And here is one query combining them both: http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/290644

Answer (score 3):

To rank by question, I concocted [this query on Data SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/290621/weighted-ranking-of-tags-by-question). It retrieves all questions, and their tags, whose score is > 10, and sorts alphabetically them by tag. The >10 criteria was to reduce the retrieve dataset size while testing the query, for speed mainly. The query retrieves raw data, which you then have to manipulate. Feel free to fork it and modify it.